# How to set the text of a cell in a row depending on order in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is probably very simple. I have a table and would like that every 4 rows has an indicator on the side to denote a separator in the table.

http://jsbin.com/AGijUNe/2/edit

I would like it so that in the page-indicator cell in each 4th row it would either say 1,2,3 etc depending on the order.

[image]

Comment: I just don't understand what you are asking. Please explain better what you want.

Comment: From your example I get the idea that you want to display the indicator _outside the table_, is that right? That's not possible, but how about [this](http://jsbin.com/IPuRoTo/1/edit). Otherwise, clarify your question.

Comment: I've added a picture of what I mean, if you look at the jsbin you'll see what I mean

Comment: Also needs to work in IE7 so psuedo elements are out of the question

Comment: @hcharge aww, you never said that in the question. Well, Javascript it is then. See Brewal's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :

```
$(function (){
  $('tr:nth-child(4n)').addClass('row4');
  $('tr:nth-child(4n) .page-indicator').each(function(i){
    $(this).text(i+1);
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/aZIWoya/1/edit?html,css,js,output)